# RewriteRule doesn't rewrite correctly

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm hosting my development site on the localhost server and I used to access it at `127.0.0.1/dev`. In the folder I have a `.htaccess` file containing following information. I'm new with the RewriteEngine and don't get this work.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ /index.php?page=$1
```

When I'm trying to access `127.0.0.1/dev/home`, I simply get a message that the page doesn't found. I can't see where rewrite is redirecting me, so I can't debug the problem in easy way. I think that you can see the problem at the first look.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this rule in `/dev/.htaccess` without leading slash in source pattern and target URL:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*) index.php?page=$0 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. Can you explain what are those `RewriteCond` rows which you added?

Comment: These 2 `RewriteCond` lines skip all existing files and directories from rewrite.